# integer type size issue

Tags: c++, 32bit-64bit

```
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdio>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, 0);
    unsigned long long int var=tv.tv_sec*1000L+tv.tv_usec/1000L;
    cout<<sizeof(var)<<endl;
    cout<<var<<endl;
    printf("%u%-15u\n", (unsigned int)(var/1000000000), (unsigned int)(var%1000000000));
    return 0;
}
```

This thing prints

```
8
1341143123970
1341143123970
```

on my 64 bit machine, but

```
8
1113191712
1113191712
```

on my 32 bit server. The second result is evidently clamped to a 32 bit number, but unsigned long long int is 8 bytes on both architectures. Where is the clamping happening then, and why?

Comment: Neither C nor C++ ever take into account how you use a value when deciding how to compute it. That you save the value in an `unsigned long long int` has *no* effect on how it is computed. The call of `foo` will be the same if you do `bool x; x = foo(y);` or if you do `int x; x = foo(y);` or `float x; x = foo(y);` or whatever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because the width of `long` is not the same on your 32-bit and 64-bit machines. The type of `tv_sec` is an arithmetic type, usually<sup>1)</sup> `long`.

You can ensure the multiplication is done with a 64-bit type by using `1000ULL` instead of `1000L`:

```
unsigned long long int var=tv.tv_sec*1000ULL+tv.tv_usec/1000ULL;
```

---

<sub>1) On `glibc` for example, it is `long`. `"In the GNU C library, time_t is equivalent to long int"` http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Simple-Calendar-Time.html</sub>

Comment: But `tv_sec` is not `long`, it's `time_t`.

Comment: I was starting from the wrong assumption that the `timeval` fields were already 64 bits. By the way, where's a list of the possible prefix for integer literals?

Comment: @LorenzoPistone in C++11, 2.14.3 and in C11, 6.4.4.1